# Neo4j - Find triplets with most similar attributes (nodes and relationships)?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a lot of triplets with different attributes for each user node (it can contain user_id, location, role for some nodes and others can be without location but with their marital status, use_car etc.) and data node.
Data node can contain location, size, origin and sometimes it will contain only the location.
I have a relation between these nodes - that has some attributes like folder_name, approved/rejected etc.

Given a new triplet, how can I find the most similar triplets by their attributes (user node + relation + data node)

Is there any functionality to do this? I will be happy to get a direction to check or minimal example.

Comment: How do you want to calculate similarity? Or you want to return user nodes that have same attribute value in data node?

Comment: @LazarĐorđević 2 steps: the first one will use the new triplet and ask which other triplets share the same attributes (user node attributes + relation attributes + data attributes). We will get a set of triplets that share the same attributes. Next stage will be to calculate the similarity like we do it with vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use [Node Similarity algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/node-similarity/) that uses the Jaccard similarity under the hood. It is available in the [Neo4j Graph Data Science library](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/). This algorithm will allow you to compare node similarity based on their attribute nodes as you call them. If you also want to compare node properties, you would have to create your own comparing sets for each node and then use the basic implementation of Jaccard similarity score: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/jaccard/

Answer (score 1):

something along these lines should get you started

```
MATCH (u:User)-->(something)<--(other:User)
WHERE u <> other
WITH u, COUNT(something) AS sharedSomethings
ORDER BY sharedSomethings DESC
```

Comment: Can you please explain? Why <>? And where is the comparison of ALL attributes of u, something and other?

Comment: @SteveS It is not optimal in my opinion to do comparison in Neo4J with all attributes of every node with every node. What you can do to use this query is to make separate nodes for significant attributes. After that you can also filter nodes if you want all atributes to be connected `WHERE sharedSomething > 10` (if you have 10 attributes)

Comment: Is there any method to do this? Maybe Jaccard? Given different triplets and new one that we got now, how to compare this new one to all others and find the largest amount of mutual attributes in users, relation and data attributes.